# why are variables in javascript much slower?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

```
var completeObj = {a: { b: { c: { d: { e: { f: 23 } } } } } };
var funcA = function(obj){
    var a = 'a',b='b',c='c',d='d',e='e',f='f';
    return obj[a][b][c][d][e][f];
}

var funcB = function(obj){
    return obj['a']['b']['c']['d']['e']['f'];
}
```

funcA is much slower than funcB，looking for varible in scope cost so much time?
test url : http://jsperf.com/static-and-dynamic-argument
thx

Comment: Because the code is doing much more??? The compiler is not <s>clever enough to realize</s> implemented to check that those variables are constants and could be inlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsperf.com/static-and-dynamic-argument/2

I took your test cases and added one to it to 'prove a point'. When you access somthing in an object via the `['key']` notation, you're doing the same thing as accessing it via `.key`. The compiler is smart enough to know that `['a']` is equivalent to `.a`. However, when you stick a variable in there, as Bergi mentioned in his comment, the compiler has no idea that `[a]` is actually `['a']`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because local variables(function-scope) become properties of an internal `Variable` object. So a call to `obj[a][b][c][d][e][f]` ends up accessing properties `a` through `f` on the `Variable` object first and then on `completeObj`.

Comment: i wanna know does accessing properties cost so much time or the compiler has some optimizions on inlined object?

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with variables or variable scope (pure local variables are actually free) but using reflection to access properties rather than constants.

`obj['a']['b']['c']['d']['e']['f'];`

is equal to `obj.a.b.c.d.e.f` so it is known even from the source code what properties will be accessed.

However, using bracket notation with variables requires figuring out at runtime what properties will be accessed and so it's completely different. In Java the former code is like using Reflection library to access properties whereas latter is same as using normal static dot access.

---

So why doesn't the compiler "realize" that the variables are static too? Well your code is completely unreasonable and JIT wasting time optimizing unreasonable code is a bad JIT.

Why does it realize that `['a']` is same as `.a` though? Well at least in my experience it was much simpler to have parser spit out same MemberAccess objects for dot and bracket access and then just check if the expression is a constant string.